# How to give python access to system wide modules in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, python-2.7, ubuntu, numpy, python-module

I have python 2.7.12 installed in Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit version). I have modules such as numpy, scipy, sympy etc. installed via pip as well. My problem is, when I open python command line via Terminal and try to import these modules, I get the following error:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Jul 10 2016, 20:42:07) 
[GCC 5.3.1 20160413] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
>>>
```

Upon doing some research, I found from this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/469801/error-importing-numpy-into-python) that if I open python command line using `/usr/bin/python` and try importing these modules, I don't get any errors.

```
$ /usr/bin/python
Python 2.7.11+ (default, Apr 17 2016, 14:00:29) 
[GCC 5.3.1 20160413] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> import scipy
>>> import sympy
>>> import matplotlib
>>> import pandas
>>>
```

But I would like to know if there is any way I can just type in `python` from Terminal and import these modules in the python command line? For example, if I write a program like this,

```
x = 2
print x
y = 5
print y
print x+y

import numpy
import scipy
import sympy
```

save it in a file named test.py in my desktop and open it using the command `/usr/bin/python test.py`, I am getting the desired output.

```
$ /usr/bin/python test.py
2
5
7
```

But if I try the same with the command `python test.py`, I get the error again

```
$ python test.py
2
5
7
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    import numpy
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

From what I understand, python doesn't have access to system wide modules since it is installed locally. If so, is there a way to make python global or the modules local to python? I have been trying for the past couple of hours to find a solution but I haven't found anything yet and I am new to Linux. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the root cause is you have several python binary under $PATH, and your system doesn't use `/usr/bin/python` by default.

1. run command `which python` to see which python is used by default
2. rename the default python file to something like 'python-2-7-12'

then try to run `python test.py` again to see if it is resolved.

Comment: another way is you can create a alias in your profile:

vim ~/.bashrc
alias python='/usr/bin/python'

Comment: The first method worked perfectly fine. When I ran `which python`, it showed `/usr/local/bin/python`. So I followed your instructions and renamed the Python file there to **Python_Default**. Now when I run python from the terminal and enter `import module`, it works. Also, `which python` now shows `/usr/bin/python`. There are like three different python files in the root directory. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @rsnaveen Did you install Python yourself? There is no reason to do that unless you have to use a specific version of Python that is different from the Python that already comes installed with Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @edwinksl I didn't know Ubuntu comes with python pre-installed. Man do I feel stupid now! Thanks for pointing that out.